# a dynamic html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

*i am new to js.trying to create a table using js.but codes are not working .what are the faults in this code?it would be a great help if anyone point out the mistakes here.*
the css is here

```
<style>
        tr{width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid black;}
        td{height:33%;width:33%;}
        .tableShape{
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            font-size:30px;
            text-align:center;
            color:red;
        }
        </style>
```

js code is here

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    </title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
    var i,j;
    var arr=new Array(3);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i]=new Array(3);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
    arr[i][j]=1;
    }}
    function tabs(){

    var s=document.createElement("table");
    s.setAttribute('class',"tableshape");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var p=s.creatChild("tr");
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
              var d=p.creatChild("td");
              d.appendTextNode(arr[i][j]);

              }
              }
              document.body.appendChild(s);
              }
    window.onLoad=tabs;
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: *but codes are not working* is vague, try to explain your issue specifically and just provide the relevant code

Comment: check my answer out, and the jsfiddle DEMO I have created for you.

Answer (score 0):

just change your `tabs` function like this:

```
function tabs() {

    var s = document.createElement("table");
    s.setAttribute('class', "tableshape");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var p = s.insertRow(i);
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var d = p.insertCell(j);
            d.innerText = arr[i][j];

        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

this is your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26nrD/1/)

The point is, if you are doing raw javascript like this, since tables have their specific DOM structure, you better create table rows and cells using `tbl.insertRow(index)` and `row.insertCell(index)` instead of creating every single node, and append it to the DOM.

Comment: i clicked on the run button .but its not showing any table or something!

Comment: ok then if you want it like this check this [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/26nrD/2/) I have updated the demo an added a RUN button which works.

Comment: i don't know what happend but no table is showing on my browser:(

Comment: what is your browser?